# Variables en url a consulta php

Tags: php, javascript

soy nueva en esto y estoy haciendo una especie de catálogo en el que por medio de una búsqueda visual con imágenes voy moviéndome por el mismo, sería algo como por ejemplo:

grupo (animal de compañía) → tipo (Perro) → clase (Chiguagua) → nombre → ficha del animal

1ª Pantalla- Grupo -> pincho en un grupo y me pasa a la siguiente pantalla donde me muestra los iconos con los tipos. Selecciono el tipo de animal y me pasa a la siguiente donde me muestra los iconos con las clases, y así hasta llegar a la pantalla donde selecciono el nombre del animal y me muestra sus datos: por ejemplo, nombre, edad, foto...

La búsqueda natural es ir pantalla a pantalla, pero podría pasar que quisiera acceder directamente a la ficha de **Rocko**, por ejemplo, porque puede haber uno que se llame así. Si la url es [www.catalogo.php](http://www.catalogo.php), cada vez que busco un dato por POST y cambio de pantalla o búsqueda, sigue siendo [www.catalogo.php](http://www.catalogo.php), mi pregunta es como acceder directamente a la ficha de Rocko vía url, sería pasar ese dato por la url y que lo recibiese la consulta que busca la ficha del animal, no? Imaginad que quiera enviarle a alguien la ficha de Rocko, para que no tenga que hacer la búsqueda por todas las pantallas hasta llegar a la ficha del animal, haría un copy/paste de la url para que la abriese directamente. Es posible?

No se si lo expliqué bien
Esto es lo que hago (resumido) para recibir la ficha

```
function objeto(){
    var elemento = document.getElementById("formulario");
    obje = document.getElementById('elemento');
    var txt='';
    txt ="'"+obje.value+"'";
    url_obje = 'elemento='+txt;
    xhr(url_obje);
}
var xmlhttp; 
function xhr(formu){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    }else{
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");// code for IE6, IE5
    }
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            var datos = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            for(var i in datos.data){
                if(datos.data[i].name != ""){
                    document.getElementById("text-flag").innerHTML = "<span class='texto'>Name: </span><span class='text'>" + datos.data[i].name + "</span>";
                }else{
                    document.getElementById("text-flag").innerHTML = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    xhttp.open("POST", "funciones_PHP/busqueda.php", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send(formu);
}
```

Y en busqueda.php la recojo de este modo

```
<?php
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    
    include 'Conexion.php';
    
    $conexion = new Conexion();
    $cnn = $conexion->getConexion();
    
    $individuo = $_POST['elemento'];
    
    $consulta = "SELECT codigo, name FROM tabla WHERE name in (".ltrim($individuo,',').") ORDER BY name;
    
    $statement = $cnn->prepare( $consulta );
    
    $valor= $statement->execute();
    
    if( $valor ){
        while( $resultado = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $data["data"][] = $resultado;
        }
        echo json_encode( $data );
    }else{
        echo "error";
    }
    $statement->closeCursor();
    $conexion = null;
    
?>
```

Gracias por la atención.

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta y quizá ni siquiera es algo que debas hacer. O sea, si tú mandas un `Chiguagua` sin más podrás obtener los datos que necesitas en la base de datos buscando por `Chiguagua`. A no ser que sea otra cosa lo que quieres, es que el lío de las rutas no lo entendí, ni eso de que vas haciendo consultas ... Quizá si explicas un poco mejor el contexto podríamos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Ok, edité la pregunta intentando explicarlo mejor, espero no haberlo liado más uf

Comment: Pues como he intuido, no tienes que liarte tanto la cabeza. Si has seleccionado a `Rocko` y quieres sus datos simplemente tienes que enviar el ID de *Rocko*  o lo que sea que lo identifique en la petición Ajax, en el servidor hacer algo así: `SELECT * FROM laTabla WHERE elID=elDatoQuePasaste`  esa consulta te daría los datos sobre `Rocko`, los devolverías  al cliente (Javascript) para mostrarlos. No hay que liarse con que si copiar URLs y demás. Ajax existe precisamente para interactuar entre cliente y servidor sin complicaciones y sin recargas de página.

Comment: Otra posibilidad interesante sería tener los datos de cada animal precargados, por ejemplo en atributos `data-` y mostrarlos de forma dinámica según sean seleccionados. Pero esto sólo conviene si no son demasiados datos ni muchos animales. De esa forma no habría idas y venidas al servidor, porque los datos estarían ya presentes, aunque no visibles.

Comment: Si @A. Cedano eso lo hago para buscar al animal y me muestra los datos sin problema. Si ahora tú me dices, quiero un perro y yo pienso le puede interesar Rocko, en lugar de decirte búscalo en el catalogo, yo te envío directamente por e-mail, por ejemplo, la url de la ficha de Rocko para que la veas. La url que tengo ahora es el nombre de la página del catálogo, tendría que concatenarle a esa url el valor correspondiente para que saliese la ficha de Rocko, no?

Comment: Si es para mandar una URL entonces puedes pasarle algo así: `www.dominio.com/animales/perros/rocko` (aquí es una URL amigable, pensando en una API) y cuando la persona pulse en !a URL verá los datos de Rocko que ya habrás programado en forma de API o de otro modo. Sea como sea no entiendo que tiene que ver Ajax aquí si hablas de mandar un email ¿?